# C# NET. Framework 2.0 | Make a delay?

Tags: c#, delay, .net-2.0

How can I make my program wait 1 Second and then doing something?
Like in NET. Framework 4.8 with Task.Delay() but I'm using NET. Framework 2.0 for a project for my old Windows 2000 Laptop. Is there something I can do?

```
    panel1.Visible = true;
    //delay
    panel2.Visible = true;
    //delay
    ...
```

Comment: `Thread.Sleep()`? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.thread.sleep?view=netframework-2.0

Comment: Or a `System.Windows.Forms.Timer`?

Comment: Thread.Sleep is not a good choice as this will block the message pump, which needs to be involved when updating UI. Setting the first panel to visible require the message pump to pump draw messages so that the panel and components on it become visible. You should use a timer, like @Charlieface mentions.

Comment: But how can i do a delay with a timer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see you are wanting to make UI panels be visible on a delay. One thing to **avoid** is any significant delay on the UI thread because your form will be unresponsive during that time and Users may think that it's crashed.

One good approach is to spawn a worker Thread to perform this delay action without blocking your UI thread. But when it comes time to change the UI panel to `Visible` it must be marshalled back onto the UI thread using [Invoke](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.invoke?view=netframework-2.0).

Here's the code I used to test this answer in **C# .Net Framework 2.0**. I posted it on [GitHub](https://github.com/IVSoftware/visibility_delay_without_blocking.git) if you'd like to try it.

```
public partial class MainForm : Form
{
    public MainForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    protected override void OnHandleCreated(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnHandleCreated(e);
        new Thread(makeVisibleOnDelay).Start();
    }

    private void makeVisibleOnDelay()
    {
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
        Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate { panel1.Visible = true; });
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
        Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate { panel2.Visible = true; });
    }
}
```

Now the panels display progressively:

[image: Now the panels display progressively]

Comment: I'm happy to hear that this solution meets your needs! One thing I should mention is that while `OnHandleCreated` is a great place to do something like this, it _can_ interfere with the Designer. For this reason it's best to check if the app is run-time or design-time using the `DesignMode` property of Form:  `if(!DesignMode) { new Thread(makeVisibleOnDelay).Start(); }`